# How make spam throw telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot

How make bot useing telegram? I know than open source of telegram open source now. (https://core.telegram.org/api)
Any idea please.

Comment: -1 general question without specific problem
Instruction is easy to find

Answer (score 0):

You can't spam with telegram bots as after x requests You'll get a too many requests error. If you want to create a telegram bot you'll have to learn a programming language first